# Finding radius and interval of convergence of unique series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, factorial

Here is the problem:

> Find the radius and the interval of convergence of $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdots (2n)\,x^{n}}{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots (2n-1)}.$$

I thought that I could write the numerator as $n!2^n$, and the denominator as $\frac{(2n)!}{(n!2^n)}$, but I am not sure that either of these are correct.  If you have any advice on how to solve the problem, it would be much appreciated! :) Thanks!

Comment: Your expressions for the numerator and denominator are both correct.

Answer (score 1):

By the way: Mathematica recognizes your function as
$${x\over 1-x}+{\sqrt{x}\arcsin\bigl(\sqrt{x}\bigr)\over(1-x)^{3/2}}\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the sum like you suggested:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot\cdots\left(2n\right)}{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot\cdots\left(2n-1\right)}x^n\right)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{n!\cdot2^n}{\frac{\left(2n\right)!}{n!\cdot2^n}}x^n\right)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{{\left(n!\right)}^2\cdot2^{2n}}{\left(2n\right)!}x^n\right)}$$
Now, the ratio test says that this sum converges if the ratio between successive terms:
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{\frac{{\left(\left(n+1\right)!\right)}^2\cdot2^{2\left(n+1\right)}}{\left(2\left(n+1\right)\right)!}x^{n+1}}{\frac{{\left(n!\right)}^2\cdot2^{2n}}{\left(2n\right)!}x^n}$$
is less than one. You can check that this fraction reduces to:
$$\frac{2n+2}{2n+1}x$$
so the radius of convergence is $1$ (and the interval of convergence is $-1<x<1$).